# c# hangman - how to show every new row the letters that are tried at the right spot

Tags: c#, list

The image below descripes the output that i have got for so far.. 
it misses the old letters that are tried.
so if a letter is guessed right, al the letters inclusive the old guess letters need to show on the point .......
now it only shows the given letter without the old letters

[image]

//

// this is the code that i got for so far

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program myProgam = new Program();
            myProgam.Start();
            Console.ReadKey();


        }
        void Start()
        {
            GalgjeSpel galgje = new GalgjeSpel(); 
            galgje.Init("eetlepel");

            List<string> woordenlijst = WoordenLijst();
           string nieuwwoord= SelecteerWoord(woordenlijst);
            galgje.Init(nieuwwoord);

           ToonWoord(nieuwwoord);Speelgalgje(galgje);

            //Console.WriteLine("Het geheime woord is: " + galgje.geheimWoord);
            //Console.WriteLine("Het geraden woord is: " + galgje.geradenWoord);
        }
        List <string> WoordenLijst()
        {
            List<string> Woordenlijst = new List<string>();
            Woordenlijst.Add("slapen");
            Woordenlijst.Add("poepen");
            Woordenlijst.Add("eten");
            Woordenlijst.Add("vakantie");
            Woordenlijst.Add("reizen");
            return Woordenlijst;
        }
       string SelecteerWoord(List<string> woorden)
        {
            GalgjeSpel gaglje = new GalgjeSpel();

            Random rnd = new Random();
           int randomwoord = rnd.Next(1, 5);
            string nieuwwoord = woorden[randomwoord];
          gaglje.geheimWoord = nieuwwoord;

            return nieuwwoord;
        }

        void ToonWoord(string woord)
        {
            GalgjeSpel galgje = new GalgjeSpel();

            Console.Write($"het geheime woord is: ");
            char[] letter = woord.ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i< woord.Length; i++)
            {
                galgje.geheimWoord += letter[i];
                Console.Write($"{letter[i]} ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(); 

            Console.Write("het geraden woord is: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < woord.Length; i++)
            {
                galgje.geradenWoord += (". ");
                Console.Write(". ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
        void ToonLetter(List<char> letters)
        {
            int i = 0;
            Console.Write("Ingevoerde letters zijn: ");
            foreach (var element in letters)
            {

                Console.Write($"{letters[i]} ");
                i += 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
        char LeesLetter(List<char> geheimeletters)
        {

            char letter;
            List<char> ingevoerdeletter = new List<char>();
            string tletter ="";

            do
            {  Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("voer een letter in: ");
                 letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                tletter =tletter + " "+  letter ;
                return letter;

            } while (geheimeletters.Contains(letter));
                {

                }

        }
        bool Speelgalgje(GalgjeSpel galgje)
        {
            //char lijst van ingevoerde letters
            List<char> ingevoerdeLetters = new List<char>();

            // char lijst van geheime letters
            List<char> geheimeletters = new List<char>();

            // zet elke geheime letter in een char array
            char[]geheimewoord = galgje.geheimWoord.ToArray();

            // voeg elke char letter toe aan lijst van geheime letters
            for (int i=0; i<geheimewoord.Length; i++)
            {
                geheimeletters.Add(geheimewoord[i]); 

                if (galgje.geradenWoord == galgje.geheimWoord)
                 {
                      return true;
                 }
                 else
                  {  char letter = LeesLetter(geheimeletters);
                      ingevoerdeLetters.Add(letter);
                      ToonLetter(ingevoerdeLetters);
                      galgje.Raadletter(letter);

                     }

            }return false;





        }
    }


////

namespace galgje2
{
    class GalgjeSpel
    {       

         public string geheimWoord;
        public string geradenWoord;
        public void Init(string geheimwoord)
        {
          this.geheimWoord = geheimwoord;
           this.geradenWoord="";
            char[] letter = new char [geheimwoord.Length];
            for (int i =0; i< letter.Length; i++)
            {
                this.geradenWoord += ".";

            }
        }
        public bool Raadletter(char letter)
        {

            char[] secretword = geradenWoord.ToArray();

            if (geheimWoord.Contains(letter))
            {
                for(int i=0; i<geheimWoord.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (geheimWoord[i]==letter)
                    {
                        secretword[i] = letter;
                        Console.Write($"{letter} ");  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write($". ");
                    }

                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine();


            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("letter does not match secretword");
            }


           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is really hard to read your code, since it is not english. Consider translating it to english so that we better can understand the intention of the code. General as a tip try to always write code in english so that if you publish it in any form (like right now) a boarder audiance can understand it.

Comment: As a general advice for the hangman game: You should maintain a set with all the previous guessed letters and only handle with a bool array which letters of the word were already revealed.

Comment: To be fair, Dutch is pretty much English with extra letters. `SelecteerWoord` is just "Select Word". `WoordenLijst` is "Word list"... I mean I agree, English would be a bit easier but it's not too difficult in this case, even if you don't speak Dutch :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback i will try to write it in english...  and charleh thats right its a bit similar ahah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the Raadletter function you show only the current letter in the console.

```
if (geheimWoord[i]==letter)
 {
    secretword[i] = letter; // you store the letter in the char array
   //you should print the array
    Console.Write($"{letter} ");  
  }
   else
   {
     Console.Write($". ");
   }
```

If you want to print all guesses letter your code should look have something similar:

```
public bool Raadletter(char letter)
        {

            char[] secretword = geradenWoord.ToArray();

            if (geheimWoord.Contains(letter))
            {
                geradenWoord = ""; //clear the sring only if contain letter
                for (int i = 0; i < geheimWoord.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (geheimWoord[i] == letter)
                    {
                        secretword[i] = letter; //store good letter to array
                    }


                }
                foreach (var c in secretword)
                {
                    geradenWoord += c;// save the word
                    // print guesses letters
                        Console.Write($"{c} ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine();


            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("letter does not match secretword");
            }


            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I found the solution with the help of your code thank you very much it helped me alot

Comment: after i have added your code i founded another problem i am facing, if i enter a wrong letter, it ask me to enter a new letter. when i enter a new letter and it is the right letter i get the message system index out of range... do you now how i can fix this problem?

Comment: just move the geradenWoord inside the if statement so you clear it only if the letter is in the word:)